# How to calculate excel function MDURATION manually using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, finance

I am now working on a financial project. I am going to use the formula in excel named MDURATION. I would like to calculate the value of MDURATION manually using programming language (Javascript). I have tried to do but I could not figure it out. When I compare the value between MDURATION in excel and my result from coding is different. Could you please tell me how to calculate this formula manually?

Comment: So this is not an excel problem - it is just you can’t do the maths.

Comment: So, can you solve this problem?

Comment: @SolarMike Can you?

Answer (score 1):

c is coupon rate per period.
y is yield per period.
m is periods per year.
n is periods remaining.

```
function modified_duration(c, y, m, n){
let macaulay_duration = ((1+y) / (m*y)) - ((1 + y + n*(c-y)) / ((m*c* ((1+y)**n - 1)) + m*y));
return macaulay_duration / (1 + y);  
}
console.log(modified_duration(0.025, 0.035, 2, 20));
```

This one's giving me the same results as excel.
=MDURATION(G7,G8,5%,7%,2)
Where g7 is 1/1/2015 and g8 is 1/1/2025

Comment: Could you tell me a fever?
where does these value come from 0.025, 0.035, 2 and 20?
5%/2 = 0.025?
7%/2 = 0.035?
2 = frequency?
20 = (G7 -  G8) * 2 ?

Comment: thank you so much. I have tried to used your code in calculating the MDURATION
for period in year basis is correct :), but when I used it in day and month basis the value is slightly different :(. example: 1/1/2015 and 1/2/2015

Comment: Yes, sorry I was short on the description last night, I couldn't get the code to post here for some reason, and I ended up deleting my whole description by mistake. The 0.025 is the 5% but divided by 2 since the 5% is per year. And 20 is the 10 years given the 2 coupon payments per year. 
I think you're right, it does give different results with dates that don't fall exactly on the payment periods. I'll probably take a better look at it later tonight.

Comment: You might want to try this code that does all the cashflow simulation to calculate the Duration & MDuration. I don't know if it'll work exactly like excel, but it receives the same parameters and it seems the programmer was trying to make it work like Excel. It's in JAVA though, but translating it to Javascript might not be that hard: https://github.com/jjonphl/finance/blob/master/src/main/java/ph/alephzero/finance/products/fixedincome/BondValuation.java

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I will try to convert Java code to JavaScript :)